# iFrame doesn't use anchor in iOS in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, iframe, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I have an iFrame with an anchor that should just show the table of my page. It works well for Chrome and Explorer on desktops but not in iOS. Here is the code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.obermatt.com/en/index/swiss-performance-index-spi-sitotmk/
top-10-stocks-table-value-2014-03-07.html#table_value" width="100%" height="605px"
border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Hier is a sample where it is included in a page:

http://www.handelszeitung.ch/invest/stocksDIGITAL/nebenwerte-starten-eine-rally-577856

This page only shows the table (bottom of the page) on desktops and Android but not in iOS.

Comment: have you use any kind of Javascript popup boxes in your page ?

Comment: This is the page I am referrring to in the iFrame: http://www.obermatt.com/en/index/swiss-performance-index-spi-sitotmk/top-10-stocks-table-value-2014-03-07.html. The only Javascript code is from Google Analytics. No popup. If you open the sample link on a desktop, it will work fine. If you open it on iOS, it doesn't find the anchor (neither in Safari nor in Chrome).

Comment: once I had the same problem , the bug was in popup box that javascript generate , honestly I don't know why ! , however the solution is to remove any javascript code that generates popup box 
, I hope this help you :)